# Is it possible to do union type punning in a C constant expression?

Tags: c, nan, unions

I have a function that converts a series of bytes into a floating point number, using an union. I use it to precisely represent some numbers that are hard to write, such as NaN and Infinity.

```
float i2f(uint32_t i)
{
    union { uint32_t i; float f; } u;
    u.i = i;
    return u.f;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I cannot use this function in places that expect a constant expression, such as static initializers:

```
// error: initializer element is not constant
float fs[2] = { i2f(0xffc00000), i2f(0x7f800000) };
```

Is there another way to achieve this same effect, such that the resulting expression is valid as a constant expression?

So far, the only way I found to represent a NaN as a constant is using the [__builtin_nan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fnan) extension, which is not portable. I would prefer something that works inside the boundaries of the C standard, if possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to declare and (more conventionally) initialize your own global `nan` constant, to use just as you could have nonportably used `__builtin_nan`?

Comment: The problem is that when I try to define my own constant, I can't use it inside an array initializer, because C doesn't think it's actually a constant.

Comment: What's wrong with the `INFINITY` and `NAN` macros in `math.h`?

Comment: A single NAN constant is not sufficient because there is [more than one kind of NaN value](https://anniecherkaev.com/the-secret-life-of-nan)

Comment: If you use `float`, there's only a few million :-). But it's true that `NAN` only provides you one of them. I think that's all you're going to get in fully portable C, since fully portable C does not guarantee any particular number of NaN values, not even one.

Comment: I attempted to make a macro version of the `i2f` function. It led to the same error if `f2` is `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard does not provide any features in strictly conforming code that would yield an *integer constant expression* for this.

The closest we could come might be creating a compound literal and taking a member of it:

```
(union { uint32_t u; float f; }) { 0xffc00000} .f
```

However, this is not a constant expression as the C standard defines it except C 2018 6.6 10 says “An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.”

What may serve your purpose is simply to define unions containing the desired values:

```
union { uint32_t u; float f; } fs[2] = { { 0xffc00000} , { 0x7f800000 } };
```

after which you would use their members, `fs[0].f`, `fs[1].f`, and so on.

Comment: Maybe this is the closest we can get. Looking at the definition of constant expression, I can't think of any other way.